# Probability of randomly selecting marbles

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

if you have 5 black marbles and 1 white marble in one bag,  when randomly selecting 4 out of the 6 marbles at once without replacement, what is the probability of the white marble being included in the 4 marbles selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the marbles were labeled with unique names: A, B, C, D, E and F, where F is the white marble. There are 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 ways to choose 4 of these 6 marbles. Only some of these have the white marble; 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 do not. So the probability of getting the white marble is 1 - 5x4x3x2 / 6x5x4x3 = 1 - 2/6 = 2/3.

Using the same argument we find the probability of getting a white when drawing 2 marbles is 1/3. This makes sense since it's the complement of our experiment. Also, drawing 6 gives us 3/3 = 1 and drawing 0 gives us 0/3 = 0. Because drawing the white in one draw is 1/6, drawing the white in five draws must be 5/6. By symmetry, drawing in three draws must be the same as its complement, 3/6 = 1/2.

In summary, the probability of drawing the white marble when drawing D of the 6 marbles is D/6 for 0 <= D <= 6.

Comment: Can you explain the 5*4*3*2 a little, and how many out of the 6*5*4*3 actually have white

Comment: @JaysenCong There are 5 ways to choose a black ball on the first draw, 4 on the 2nd, 3 on the 3rd and 2 on the 4th. So, 5x4x3x2 is the number of ways to draw 4 balls without drawing the white ball at all. Because there are 6x5x4x3 ways to draw any four balls, the number of ways to draw a white must be 6x5x4x3 - 5x4x3x2.